# Updating the global integer variable

Tags: global, drools

I am modifying the global integer variable with some value in the Rule 1.
I need to get this modified value in some other rule say Rule 2.

```
global Integer deviceCapacity; 

rule "Rule 1"
dialect "java"
no-loop true
when
    $snrData : SensorDataVO(getWeightOffset().size()>0,
    $initOffset:getInitialOffset());
then
    for(Integer iOff:$snrData.getWeightOffset()){
        $snrData.getOffsetChngesInterval().add(iOff-$initOffset);
        insert (new NotificationVO(iOff-$initOffset));
    }
    deviceCapacity=$snrData.getDeviceCapacity();
end


rule "Rule 2"
dialect "java"
no-loop true
when
    $mstData : MasterDataVO();
    $notification:NotificationVO((getOffsetWeight()/4).
    equals($mstData.getRodentWeight()));
then
    System.out.println("Abhijeet--"+deviceCapacity);
end
```

I am not able to access the updated deviceCapacity value in Rule 2,as i want to use the deviceCapacity value in place of "4" and want to do this until the deviceCapacity becomes 0 (deviceCapacity--).
Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the value of the *object reference* stored in a DRL global only by using the API:

```
then
//...
kcontext.getKieRuntime().setGlobal( "deviceCapacity",
                                    $snrData.getDeviceCapacity() );
end
```

Clearly, this is ugly and not checked at compile time. You might consider writing a wrapper

```
class IntWrapper {
    private int value;
    // getter, setter
}

global IntWrapper deviceCapacity;
```

Then you could do

```
deviceCapacity.setValue( $snrData.getDeviceCapacity() );
```

Or make `int value` public...

Comment: Thanks laune. I have changed my approach now. I am not taking any global integer variable , its added to the object as a fact which i can utilize in the DRL files.This make the logic more simple.

Comment: This is frequently the better approach.